# ExpressJS - Routing Function

Tags: node.js, express

I created a separate JS file for specific server functions. Sample code as follow:

**my-data.js**

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
exports.getData = function (request, response) {
    var myData = [
        {
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "value": 2
        },
    ];
    response.json(myData);
};
```

In my **app.js**, I'm trying to call that specific function when the request has been made.

**Working sample of app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var myData = require("./lib/my-data.js");

app.engine(".html", require("ejs").__express);
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Line below is what I'm trying to achieve.
//app.get("/get-data", myData.getData(request, response));

// Working line
app.get("/get-data", function(request, response) {
    myData.getData(request, response);
});

app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.render("index");
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
```

It bothers me that the line `app.get("/get-data", myData.getData(request, response));` doesn't work while

```
app.get("/get-data", function(request, response) {
        myData.getData(request, response);
});
```

does.

What is the difference between the two approach?

I prefer using the first one since it's clean and precise but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried: `app.get("/get-data", myData.getData);`?

Comment: Hi @NelsonYeung, it did work. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can tag the question as answered? Also, can you briefly explain why my approach didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get("/get-data", myData.getData);` fixes this issue.

`app.get` allows you to supply a *callback function*, which is the one that you supply as the second parameter.

I'm going to simplify this problem and call that function `get(string, func)`. Inside this function, typically it's going to call the function that you supplied:

```
function get(string, func) {
  var request = "foo";
  var response = "bar";
  // ...
  func(request, response);
}
```

So you have to pass the name of the function for it to correctly call your function, therefore `app.get("/get-data", myData.getData);` works.

However, If you supply the second parameter as this `get("/get-data", myData.getData(request, response));`, as in your first case, you are no longer supplying the `func` parameter with a function but just a value returned from your `myData.getData(...)` function.

For example, if your function is this:

```
function getData(req, res) {
  return 1;
}
```

The `get` function will end up doing something like:

```
get("foo", 1) {
  // ...
  1(request, response);
}
```

In the second case:

```
app.get("/get-data", function(request, response) {
  myData.getData(request, response);
});
```

This now passes an *anonymous function* as the callback and inside it you are just calling your own function and therefore will work as expected.